# Dexguard release build missing .so file

Tags: android, dexguard, sqlcipher-android, cardio

I use Dexguard for my release build, but I got this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/myapp.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/myapp.app-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/myapp.app-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libi.so"
```

I use Card.IO and SQLCipher which contains native code. I got this exception after I added to my project the Card.IO library.
If I just click on the play button in android studio everything is okay, but in release version my app does not work.

Can you help me how can I solve my problem?

Comment: were you able to fix this issue? if yes, please share steps.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask questions like this directly to support@guardsquare.com . It looks like that DexGuard did remove the Card.IO native library as it does not detect its use. Try to add specific

```
-keepresourcefiles lib/**/libXXX.so
```

rules, where XXX refers to the name of the Card.IO native library.